# how to send different length sentence in UART protocol

Tags: vhdl

I have build a UART module, 1stop bit 8 data bits  1 start bit,  in vhdl which works good (checked with computer program and usb-to-ttl adapter).

I have [EMIC2](https://www.parallax.com/product/30016) which use and it works with UART also .

my goal is to have a bigger module which will contain the uart module and will send full messages out in uart .

I want to have like 5 messages to be selected ,each with a different length, and each messages should be send to the uart module 1 byte at a time untill the end of the message .
I thought to do it with 5 different size FIFOs and to have a mux to selected between them, and each on each fifo ill enter the message byte byte and run on it .
 But I wanted to ask if there is maybe a easier way to do it ?

Also I wanted to ask if there is a way to initialization a fifo ?

Comment: Can you explain a little more the type of messages you want to send? Are the 5 messages always the same or do they just come from different parts of your design. In any case I wouldn't advise you to use so many FIFOs when only one can be used by implementing an arbiter just before it

Comment: @A.Kieffer yeah the 5 messages are always the same .for example In my overall project I also have buttons so if you press them I want the emic2 to say " calling to first person" /two/third, and for one of the buttons it would say "Coudln't find the branch you asked for". According to emic each message also should start with "S" and end with carrtige return ,13 hex

Comment: To my mind you should use a simple ROM containing your messages and use pointer to access each one. Then you can forward them to a FIFO if you need to cross two clock domains.

Comment: It got a bit too complicated for me so I just made them all the same length with a lot of space in the short once , as  I found out that  the EMIC ignore spaces